# Iterating quicksort steps - visualisation in turtle

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort, turtle-graphics

I'm writing a simple app in `Python3` with `Turtle`. It visualizes `quicksort` algorithm. I want to improve my app so I can show each step of the algorithm by waiting for a click from user.

I've tried simple `input()` in the middle of the algorithm but this requires the console to be active while the app window goes to the background.
Now I'm trying to use `onscreenclick()` but when algorithm goes to certain point, it stops listening for mouse events.

How can I do it? Is there any other way to do this?

```
def partition(array, start, end):                  
    global clickedFlag
    pivotIndex = start                                  
    pivotValue = array[end]                             
    for i in range(start, len(array) - 1):              
        if array[i] < pivotValue:                       
            if clickedFlag:
                swap(array, i, pivotIndex)                  
                pivotIndex += 1                            
                clickedFlag = False                                     
            else:
                while clickedFlag == False:
                    onscreenclick(clicked)
                    listen()
    swap(array, pivotIndex, end)                        
    return pivotIndex

def clicked(x,y):
    global clickedFlag
    clickedFlag = True
    return clickedFlag
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you concentrate the "waiting for click" logic in one place and not mix it with the rest of the sorting logic.

For example

```
def waitForClick():
    global clickedFlag
    clickedFlag = False
    while clickedFlag == False:
         onscreenclick(clicked)
         listen()

...
    if array[i] < pivotValue: 
        waitForClick()
        swap(array, i, pivotIndex)                  
        pivotIndex += 1                            
...
```

Comment: It makes no sense to call `onscreenclick(clicked)` in a loop, it simply associates a handler function with an event.  And it makes no sense to call `listen()` as it allows a window to receive *keyboard* events and has nothing to do with mouse clicks.  This tight `while` loop will likely *block* mouse events from happening.

Comment: I was merely pointing out the issue of embedding the UI control too intricately with the processing logic. I'm not familiar enough with these UI functions to address those concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding of mouse events in turtle graphics.  They arrive as independent events and you can't simply stop your running code to wait for one to happen.  Your code has to be designed to respond to events.

I believe the simpler [Zelle Graphics](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) package may be better suited to your needs.  It's `getMouse()` routine will stop your program and wait for the user to click the mouse.

Below I've implemented a crude visualization of your (completed) code which prints the shuffled array to the console.  In the graphics window, starting at the bottom, the value at the pivot index is shown in red in the center with the remaining array values shown on either side.  As you click in the window, the program advances, and the graphics window updated, until the sorted array is printed in the console window.  A further click quits the program:

```
from random import shuffle
from graphics import *

def swap(array, i, j):
    array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]

def partition(array, start, end):
    global text

    pivotIndex = start
    pivotValue = array[end]

    for i in range(start, len(array) - 1):
        if array[i] < pivotValue:

            ##########################################
            # crude visualization example
            text = [obj.clone() for obj in text]

            left, pivot, right = text

            left.setText(str(array[:pivotIndex]))
            pivot.setText(str(array[pivotIndex]))
            right.setText(str(array[pivotIndex + 1:]))

            for obj in text:
                obj.draw(window).move(0, -10)

            window.getMouse()                        #
            ##########################################

            swap(array, i, pivotIndex)
            pivotIndex += 1

    swap(array, pivotIndex, end)
    return pivotIndex

def quickSort(array, low, high):
    if low < high:
        pivotIndex = partition(array, low, high)

        quickSort(array, low, pivotIndex - 1)
        quickSort(array, pivotIndex + 1, high)

########################################################################################
# crude visualization setup
window = GraphWin("Sorting Visualization", 800, 600)

text = [Text(Point(200, 600), ""), Text(Point(400, 600), ""), Text(Point(600, 600), "")]
text[1].setTextColor('red')                                                            #
########################################################################################

array = list(range(20))
shuffle(array)
print(array)

quickSort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

print(array)

window.getMouse()
window.close()
```

[image]